# SQL - find duplicates in two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with four columns, where `col1` & `col2` contain similar values (INT). I now want to know if there are duplicates in `col1` and/or `col2`. i.e.,

```
col1 | col2
-----+-----
111  | 222
333  | 444
111  | 333
555  | 111
```

→ Duplicates: `111` (3x) and `333` (2x).

I am using SQLite, but I think this is a basic SQL question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a count of each element use UNION ALL in a subquery, then GROUP BY on the result of that:

```
SELECT col, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT col1 AS col FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col2 FROM Table1
) T1
GROUP BY col
```

Add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` if you only wish to see the duplicated values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two columns where the values are compatible (that is, 333 in one column represents the same "thing" as 333 in the other column) then this is called *repeating groups*.  This is a violation of [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

If the values were in a single column, finding duplicates would be easy:

```
CREATE TABLE pairs (
  pair_id INT,
  value   INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (pair_id, value)
);

INSERT INTO pairs VALUES
(1, 111), (1, 222),
(2, 333), (2, 444),
(3, 111), (3, 333),
(4, 555), (4, 111);

SELECT value, COUNT(*)
FROM pairs
GROUP BY value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Join the table to itself to see if there are any duplicates.

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from table t1 inner join table t2 
  on t1.col1 = t2.col2
```